# Rails Displaying Flash Messages from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to display some error messages from my model in Rails. Currently, when an exception is caught in my `test` model and raised, the messages are returned as expected in the errors scope of my object. The messages are returned as follows:

```
 {:key1=>["Your key needs to be different."], 
 :key2=>["Another exception"]}
```

This is perfect, as the correct exceptions are being thrown for the correct errors. What I'm trying to do now is bind these messages to the flash scope so that I can display them on my view. In my controller, when I have an exception, I then bind it to the `flash[:error]` scope as follows:

```
 flash[:error] = @test.errors.messages
 render :new
```

Upon doing this, my errors are bound to the flash scope, but when I output them on my view, they are displayed as follows:

```
 [:error, {:key1=>["Your key needs to be different."], :key2=>["Another exception"]}]
```

All I'd like to do is display each one of these messages so that they look to be like:

```
 Your key needs to be different.
 Another exception.
```

Notice that in the above example, all that will be rendered is the message text.

Will you please point me in the right direction as to what I need to change either in my controller or in my view to achieve the desired output above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when I looped over `@test.errors.messages` in the following construct, I ended up with a 2-Dimensional array:

```
[:key1, ["Your key needs to be different."]] 
[:key2, ["Another exception"]]
```

Since this is a multidimensional array, I was able to then simply loop over the array in my erb and get the value to display as requested in my question:

```
<% for i in flash[:error] %>
    <%= i[1].first %><br />
<% end %>
```

Returns on the screen:

> Your key needs to be different.
>   Another exception.

I'm always open to suggestions, so if there's a better way to handle this, then please advise! Otherwise, this does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The one place I immediately see for improvement is in the hash you're passing.

If there's not a specific reason you're wrapping your strings in an array, you can eliminate the array:

```
{ 
  :key1 => "Somebody poisoned the watering hole!",   
  :key2 => "There's a snake in my boot."
}
```

That will both simplify your code and eliminate the two-dimensional array you didn't seem to be intending to create.

If there is a reason you're wrapping your strings in an array (multiple messages per key?), you'll need to revisit your iterator; the way it's written now, it's only going to display the `first` string for any given key.